# sessionDidEndPlayback not being called

Tags: spotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0

I've included the SPSessionPlaybackDelegate and have included the method:

```
-(void)sessionDidEndPlayback:(SPSession *)aSession {
NSLog(@"song ended");

}
```

Yet this is not called when the song ends its playback naturally. Is there something I should be doing extra to implement this delegate? Other such methods are being called at the appropriate time:

```
-(void)sessionDidLoginSuccessfully:(SPSession *)aSession; {

}
```

Comment: I have the same problem, weird that you asked this today.  Is something wrong with the service or are we doing something incorrectly?

Comment: So, the method should look like this `-(void)sessionDidEndPlayback:(id <SPSessionPlaybackProvider>)aSession {}`, but it's still not working for me.

Comment: I think we are doing something incorrectly, it hasn't ever worked for me. I may be implementing the SPSession delegate incorrectly, because some of the other callbacks from that delegate are also not working. I've tried a few things and still haven't gotten to the bottom of it.

Answer (score 3):

`sessionDidEndPlayback:` is part of the `SPSessionPlaybackDelegate` protocol, not `SPSessionDelegate`. It's called on whichever object is set as the `playbackDelegate` of the session object.

*However*, if you're using `SPPlaybackManager` for audio playback, that class sets itself as the session's `playbackDelegate` when you create it, and requires that it stays that way.

Currently, `SPPlaybackManager` doesn't provide a delegate method for the track ending, so the way to do this in the current release of CocoaLibSpotify is to observe `SPPlaybackManager`'s `currentTrack` property — when it goes `nil`, you know playback has ended.

The `dev` branch of CocoaLibSpotify has just added the method `playbackManagerIsFinishingPlayback:` to `SPPlaybackManager`'s delegate protocol.

Comment: Could you tell me where Can I find the playbackManagerIsFinishingPlayback method. I have searched a lot but couldn't find it

Comment: As the answer says, it's on the dev branch of the project on gitHub. It's not in a stable release yet.